# Do I need to make an app to access public Facebook information for personal use using the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I'm trying to use the facebook graph api to get public information from business pages, but I'm confused by the app review system. I don't intend to make an app that interfaces with anyone; I just want to get other businesses' information on public pages for my own use. Is there an easy way to do this? Can I use an app token without making an actual app? I've read all of the documentation but I'm still lost.

Comment: Unless someone was to give you their token ... of course you need to create your own app first. And to get information from pages you do not have administrative control over, you will have to submit your app for feature review, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: Will I need to submit for login review, or can I just use an app token to access the page data I'm interested in?

Comment: Not sure; traditionally the app access token allowed access to some data, but I wouldn’t be surprised if that got more restricted by now.